# aws-sdk gem: SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am using `aws-sdk gem`. i want to stop and start aws instance using 'aws-sdk' gem.

Below is my code to start an already stooped amazon instance but it is giving me error as `SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known`

```
ec2 = AWS::EC2::Client.new(
  region: 'us-west-2c',
  credentials: {:access_key_id => 'XXXXXXXXX',:secret_access_key => 'XXXXXXXXXXX'}
)



resp = ec2.start_instances({
  instance_ids: ["i-xxxxxx"], 
  additional_info: "String"
})
```

Please help

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of research i came to know that i was specifying wrong region.

My region was 'us-west-2' and i was using region as 'us-west-2c' Which was not a region but availability zone.

After changing region to 'us-west-2' it works

```
AWS.config(
region: 'us-west-2',
access_key_id: 'xxxxxx',
secret_access_key: 'xxxxxxxxx'
)

ec2 = AWS::EC2::Client.new



resp = ec2.start_instances({
  instance_ids: ["i-xxxxxxxxx"], 
  additional_info: "String"
})
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case I had eu-east-1 instead of us-east-1.